# Error in simple python module

Tags: python, shell

I tried to write a little python script today but have failed horribly. Why is it that the code below gives me the following error after being called from the shell?

Error

```
File "./testmod.py", line 15, in <module>
    printdnsfile(sys.argv[1])
  File "./testmod.py", line 10, in printdnsfile
    print(socket.gethostbyname(str(line)))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def printdnsfile(file):
    file= open (file,"r")
    import socket
    dest = open("/dnsfile.txt",'w')
    for line in file:
        print(socket.gethostbyname(str(line)))
        print>>dest, str(",".join([line,socket.gethostbyname(line)])+'\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    printdnsfile(sys.argv[1])
```

I tested the socket module in the python-console and it worked as expected. Is there an error with my code or is this a problem with my configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have an empty line in your input file. Try checking your line before you gethostbyname.

```
def printdnsfile(file):
    file= open (file,"r")
    import socket
    dest = open("/dnsfile.txt",'w')
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            print(socket.gethostbyname(str(line)))
            print>>dest, str(",".join([line,socket.gethostbyname(line)])+'\n')
```

Comment: I don't have an empty line in my input file, however my problem nevertheless got fixed by using your suggestion :). Curious why that is though. Anyway, Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget about the final line in the file. Sometimes it doesn't show up very well in your text editor. That could be it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is that `line` doesn't contain the expected value. To make sure about that you could add a `print line` statement before the line that is failing or use [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) to debug the program.