# Finding ip address - python's socket module

Tags: python, sockets

code

```
import socket
line = 'http://www.permobil.com/en/Corporate/'
IP = socket.gethostbyname(line)
```

error

```
IP = socket.gethostbyname(line)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I know there are several answers for the same error, but none helped
i looked [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332065/finding-ip-address-using-pythons-socket-module) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185080/error-in-simple-python-module)
while others answers were not applicable.

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2805413/3649209

Comment: Other questions: Have you tried it with a well known domain name like google.com, does it work for that domain? Are you behind a corporate proxy? Are you sure the DNS server for `permobil.com` are set up correctly? Are you using unix? If so, does the unix DNS lookup command: `host permobil.com` give an IP address successfully from your location?

Comment: it works for all the domains with base URL like google.com, permobil.com

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import socket

ip = socket.gethostbyname("permobil.com")
print ip
```

Comment: i already know that this works, but can i get the base URL for a website

Comment: which would be permobil.com in our case

Comment: I don't understand? All you need to do is to parse your string and get right part

Comment: but if i have tons of such websites to parse in a json file, would i be manually removing http n all that stuff to make my string permobil.com

Comment: write function that does that for you, dont forget about https too, and then pass it to socket function, there is no other way

Answer (score 0):

```
import socket
from urlparse import urlparse

parsed_uri = urlparse('http://www.permobil.com/en/Corporate/' )
domain = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
domain = domain.replace("http://","")
domain = domain.replace("www.", "")
domain = domain.replace("/", "")
IP = socket.gethostbyname(domain)
```